# GEOSwift with Google Maps iOS SDK (Draw a polygon)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, geoswift

I am using GEOSwift library (https://github.com/GEOSwift/GEOSwift)

I need help in:

1 - How can I draw polygon geometry data on Google Maps, Here is the code:

```
let geometry = try! Geometry(wkt: "POLYGON((35 10, 45 45.5, 15 40, 10 20, 35 10))")
```

2 - How can I get Coordinates (lat, long) from the Geometry (`geometry`) back in form of string or `CLLocationCoordiantes`

Thanks ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you're using Google Maps SDK for iOS version 3.3.0 and GEOSwift version 5.1.0.

You have a polygon (without holes) represented as WKT and you want to show it on a Google Map. Specifically, you probably want to end up with a [GMSPolygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_polygon)

If you know that your WKT will always be a polygon, you can actually write

```
let polygon = try! Polygon(wkt: "POLYGON((35 10, 45 45.5, 15 40, 10 20, 35 10))")
```

If you can't guarantee that, you can do what you wrote initially

```
let geometry = try! Geometry(wkt: "POLYGON((35 10, 45 45.5, 15 40, 10 20, 35 10))")
```

and then extract the polygon using `if case let`/`guard case let`/`switch case let`:

```
switch geometry {
case let .polygon(polygon):
    // Do something with polygon
default:
    // handle other types of Geometry or fail here
}
```

Check the [definition of Geometry](https://github.com/GEOSwift/GEOSwift/blob/master/GEOSwift/Core%20Types/Geometry.swift) that shows the other cases you might care to handle.

Once you have `polygon: Polygon`, you can get the points that represent its exterior:

```
let points = polygon.exterior.points
```

`Polygon.exterior` gives you a `Polygon.LinearRing` and `Polygon.LinearRing.points` gives you an array of `Point`.

Now that you have `points`, you can map them into an array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D`

```
let coords = points.map { p in CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: p.y, longitude: p.x) }
```

Note that y goes with latitude and x goes with longitude.

Now that you have `coords`, you can create a `GMSPath` using its mutable subclass, [GMSMutablePath](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_mutable_path.html):

```
let path = GMSMutablePath()
for c in coords {
    path.addCoordinate(c)
}
```

You can use that path to create a GMSPolygon:

```
let polygon = GMSPolygon(path: path)
```

Then you just need to add it to you map:

```
polygon.map = yourMap
```